# Where does the version string in generated Google Endpoint libs come from?

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

When I run the `installClientLibs` from Android Studio (with gradle command as well) for an Endpoint, the jar is generated with this name:

```
libEndpoint-v1-1.18.0-rc-SNAPSHOT
```

But since some days ago, it's being generated as:

```
libEndpoint-v1-1.19.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Where do the "18.0-rc" and the "19.0" come from? Why did it change? Is it due to a SDK update maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the version of the Google libraries:

- google-api-client-1.18.0-rc
- google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc
- google-http-client-1.18.0-rc
- google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc
- google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc

These libraries are used to generate android client library for your Android module.

You can see them if you expand ***External Libraries*** section in Android Studio.

You can also check what is the latest version in Maven Repository. Just go to http://search.maven.org/ and type one of them. You will notice that **1.19.0** is the newest one as you posted.

If you would like avoid update Android module gradle file every time version changes, you can set your dependency like this:

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

where backend is the name of the module. By the way, this is how Google Cloud Endpoint template generates configuration for a while. If you find any difficulties applying this way, try creating new project and generate backend module.